# Remote database access (From Parallels power panel)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, remote-access

So i have this server (hosting service) known as Parallels power.

Now on this hosting service my database is configured and stored.

Now the database is MySQL and if i go to its administration panel i get the following details:

```
    Server version: 5.5.33
Protocol version: 10
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
User: root@localhost
```

Now i want to connect to this database to this database remotely however i am not sure how?

In my paralle control pannel i get a container name for the host server `Container ****.unoeuro-server.com` However this wasnt the host i can connect to my database at.

So i decided to send them an email to check if i was blocked out and they replied:

```
 ****.unoeuro-server.com is not your Host and your firewall is not blocking outside calls.
```

So my question to you guys how the hell can i connect to the database remotely :S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have privilege in phpMyAdmin to manage users (root privilege), you can create a user with global access to it. so you can access to your panel from desired remote Host.
**UPDATE:** It seems you have root privilege to manage users in phpMyAdmin, so when you logged in to your phpMyAdmin panel go to `User` tab then click `add user` link then fill your information but in host field select `any host` or `your desired host`.